How to tell whether a probability is conditional?

In a class of $32$ children, $18$ are Chinese, $8$ are Malay, $4$ are Indian and $2$ are Eurasian. One child is chosen at random from the class. Another child is then chosen at random from the remaining children. A third child is then chosen from the remaining children. Find the probability that the three children chosen are of different races, given that the second child is Chinese.

I am confused about the wording of the question. My confusion is on whether I should use conditional probability for this problem.
When the problem statement says "Find the probability of A given B", I always think of conditional probability, in which case $$P(\text{different races given second Chinese})= \dfrac{P(\text{different races and second Chinese})}{P(\text{second Chinese})}\\= \dfrac{(21/310)}{(9/16)}=\dfrac{56}{465}.$$
However couldn't the question be equivalently rephrased as follows? "Find the probability of picking three children of different races where the second child is Chinese." In this case the probability is just $$P(\text{different races and second Chinese})= \dfrac{21}{310}.$$
This question was part of a recent probability test in which I lost marks for giving the first answer (56/465). I would like clarification on whether my conception is correct.

Yes, you want the conditional probability here.

Should add:  I don't agree with your numbers (though I did it hastily and might have made an error).  I suggest:  edit your post to include your computation.

@lulu For what it's worth, my answer is $~\dfrac{112}{31 \times 30} = \dfrac{56}{465}.~$ However, I may have made an arithmetic error.

@user2661923  Let's see...using the first letter of each ethnicity, the other two kids must be one of ${MI, ME, IE}$ in either order.  Thus the conditional probability is $\frac 2{31\times 30}\times (8\times 4+8\times 2+4\times 2)=\frac {56}{465}$ .  Again, just did it fast.

@lulu I had a typo in my previous comment, which I have now edited.

@user2661923  Ah, then we are in agreement.

Usually, when a problem statement says, "Find the probability of $A$ given $B$," they want you to find the probability of $A$ given $B$, which is a conditional probability, not the probability of $A$ and $B$. Why is this in doubt?

@DavidK I was just confused with the wording of the question. I myself always think of conditional probability when the problem statement says "Find the probability of A given B". However could the question not be rephrased as follows? : "Find the probability of picking three children of different races where the second child is Chinese?" In that case the answer should be 21/310. I m saying this because this question was part of a recent probability test and I lost marks for the answer 56/465. This question was posted just to get clarification on whether my conception is correct.

We all agree that the answer to the question as written is $56/465$. Unless the grader found errors in your derivation (there would have to be at least two so they can cancel out), I don’t see a reason not to give full credit.



Find the probability that the three children chosen are of different races, given that the second child is Chinese.

$$P(\text{different races }\textbf{given}\text{ second Chinese})=\dfrac{56}{465}.$$

This is correct.  Equivalently: If the second chosen child is Chinese, find the probability that the three children chosen are of different races.

However couldn't the question be equivalently rephrased as follows? "Find the probability of picking three children of different races where the second child is Chinese." In this case the probability is just $$P(\text{different races }\textbf{and}\text{ second Chinese})= \dfrac{21}{310}.$$

This new question means Find the probability that the three children chosen are of different races such that the second child is Chinese (the word "where" has been replaced without altering meaning), and its correct answer is indeed $\frac{21}{310}.$ So, it is not equivalent to the original question.

I don't think that it is a coincidence that my answer agrees with the OP's first computation.  So, although the OP didn't actually describe his thinking, I went ahead and posted my answer.

Yes, you do want to use conditional probability, but (in this instance) the application of it is convoluted.
Let $~A~$ denote the event that the $~3~$ children are of three different races.
Let $~B~$ denote the event that the 2nd child is Chinese.
Then, you are asked for
$$p(A ~| ~B ~) = \frac{p(A \cap B)}{p(B)}. \tag1 $$
So, the entire problem is reduced to computing the numerator and denominator, in (1) above.  Since this problem is a combinatorics-oriented problem, I will express the probabilities of $~p(A \cap B)~$ and $~p(B)~$ combinatorically.
The denominator is easy.  There are $~\displaystyle \binom{32}{1}~$ ways of selecting the 2nd student, of which $~\displaystyle \binom{18}{1}~$ of these ways will result in the person being Chinese.
Therefore,
$$p(B) = \frac{\binom{18}{1}}{\binom{32}{1}} = \frac{18}{32}.$$

To express the $~p( ~A \cap ~B ~) ~$ as $~\dfrac{N}{D},~$ the simplest approach is to assume that order of selection is relevant in both the computation of $~N~$ and the computation of $~D.$
So, $~D = \dfrac{32!}{(32 - 3)!} = 32 \times 31 \times 30.$
Computation of $~N,~$ the numerator is convoluted, and must be broken down into the following mutually exclusive cases, that must then be summed together:

Malay, Chinese, Indian. 
$~\displaystyle \binom{8}{1} \times \binom{18}{1} \times \binom{4}{1} = 8 \times 18 \times 4.$

Malay, Chinese, Eurasian. 
Similar to the previous bullet point, the computation is $~8 \times 18 \times 2.$

Indian, Chinese, Malay. 
$4 \times 18 \times 8.$

Indian, Chinese, Eurasian. 
$4 \times 18 \times 2.$

Eurasian, Chinese, Malay. 
$2 \times 18 \times 8.$

Eurasian, Chinese, Indian. 
$2 \times 18 \times 4.$


Therefore,
$$N = [ ~8 \times 18 \times 4 ~] + [ ~8 \times 18 \times 2 ~]
+ [ ~4 \times 18 \times 8 ~] + [ ~4 \times 18 \times 2 ~] \\
+ [ ~2 \times 18 \times 8 ~] + [ ~2 \times 18 \times 4 ~].
$$
Then, $~N~$ can be re-expressed as
$$N = 18 \times \left\{ ~[ ~8 \times 4 ~] + [ ~8 \times 2 ~]
+ [ ~4 \times 8 ~] + [ ~4 \times 2 ~] 
+ [ ~2 \times 8 ~] + [ ~2 \times 4 ~] ~\right\} $$
$$= 18 \times 112.$$
Therefore
$$p(A \cap B) = \frac{N}{D} = \frac{18 \times 112}{32 \times 31 \times 30}.$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{p(A \cap B)}{p(B)} = \frac{\frac{18 \times 112}{32 \times 31 \times 30}}{\frac{18}{32}}. \tag1 $$
Notice that in (1) above, both the numerator and the denominator have a common fraction of $~\dfrac{18}{32}.$
Cancelling this out gives
$$\frac{p(A \cap B)}{p(B)} = \frac{\frac{112}{31 \times 30}}{1} = \frac{112}{31 \times 30} = \frac{56}{465}.$$

$~\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
Hijacking the analysis in one of the comments of lulu, the problem can be re-interpreted as a purely probability problem that does not involve conditional probability.
Since the 2nd child chosen is Chinese, as far as the selection of the 1st and 3rd children are concerned, you are now working in a universe of $~31~$ people, of which the number of Malay, Indian, and Eurasian are $~8, ~4,~$ and $~2~$ respectively.
So, the probability can be expressed as
$$\dfrac{N}{D} ~: ~D = 31 \times 30,$$
where
$$N = [ ~8 \times (4 + 2) ~] + [ ~4 \times (8 + 2) ~] + [ ~2 \times (8 + 4) ~] = 112.$$
So,
$$\frac{N}{D} = \frac{112}{31 \times 30} = \frac{56}{465}.$$

I was just confused with the wording of the question. I myself always think of conditional probability when the problem statement says "Find the probability of A
given B". However could the question not be rephrased as follows? : "Find the probability of picking three children of different races where the second child is Chinese?" In that case the answer should be 21/310.

@AshmeePragnaRoy No, it can't be re-phrased that way, because of the problem composer's use of the word given, as in "given that the 2nd child is Chinese".  To layman, your interpretation is plausible.  To mathematicians experienced in the use of the word given, in probability problems, your interpretation is unacceptable.

Order doesn't matter. We can consider that this chinese child appears in 1st position.
After this chinese child, what is the probability that child n°2 is not chinese ? $\frac{14}{31}$
But if we start like this, we will not be able to compute probability that child n°3 is ok.
Probability that child n°2 is Malay is $\frac{8}{31}$, and in this case, proba of success is $\frac{6}{30}$
Probability that child n°2 is Indian is $\frac{4}{31}$, and in this case, proba of success is $\frac{10}{30}$
Probability that child n°2 is Eurasian is $\frac{2}{31}$, and in this case, proba of success is $\frac{12}{30}$
Total proba of success is $\dfrac{8 \times 6 + 4 \times 10 + 2 \times 12}{31 \times 30}= \dfrac{112}{31\times 30}$
As far as I remember, all problems with conditional probability can also be solved with simple probability. We just need to ajust the universe.
